# Different between AdControl and AdMediatorControl

Tags: win-universal-app, ads

May I know the Different between AdControl and AdMediatorControl because I had implemented this two at the same time in my code.

Answer (score 1):

**Ad Mediator Control**

The recommended method of using the Microsoft Advertising AdControl to show banner ads (not interstitial ads) in your apps is to use the Microsoft Ad Mediator control in your UI.

[image]

**AdControl**

The Microsoft Advertising AdControl can be used by itself in .NET and JavaScript apps. The libraries for the AdControl contain APIs to show banner ads and interstitial ads.

[MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt463352(v=msads.30).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know ,AdControl and AdMediatorControl are all banner, but there are some difference . For example AdControl only add one  ads at a time , but AdMediatorControl can add multiple ads at a time

AdControl for UWP

1.Install  [Microsoft Store Service SDK](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/229b7858-2c6a-4073-886e-cbb79e851211)

Add a namespace declaration to your page

```
xmlns:UI="using:Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI"
```

More details you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/adcontrol-in-xaml-and--net)

2.install [AdDuplex](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6930860a-e64b-4b46-9d72-62d7fddda077)

Add a namespace declaration to your page

```
xmlns:adduplex="using:AdDuplex"
```

AdMediator for windows 8.1

1.install [Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows and Windows Phone 8.x](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bb4b3020-9b56-4e81-a314-e40cff00fb52)

Add a namespace declaration to your page

```
xmlns:Windows81="using:Microsoft.AdMediator.Windows81"
```

More details you can see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn864355.aspx)